# can not import PIL ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I successfully installed `PIL`.

But when create new project I can`t import PIL. 
Error:

```
(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL')
```

I am using Python 3.8 and `tkinter`.

Comment: How did you install `PIL`? Where did you run this code

Comment: Please, provide the code where do you importing it and how did you install it. And consider using Pillow instead of PIL

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the python environment you're running is not the same environment that pip is updating. It's pretty common if you have more than one python installation.

Make sure that your OS environment variables for pip and python are directed toward appropriate script files of a particular install.